# php loop not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone tell me why my loop is running twice? It's printing my jumbotron div twice or more than that. Whenever I upload multiple images, this happens. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row jumbotron">
        <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($set as $value){
                $content['added_date'][$i] = $value->added_date;
                $content['file_name'][$i] = $value->file_name;
                $i++;
            }

            for ($j=1; $j < $i ; $j++) { 
                //echo $j;
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:#33CCFF">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url().$content['file_name'][$j]; ?>" style="width:200px;height:150px">
        </div>

        <?php
            if ($j % 4 == 0) {
                echo '<a onclick="javascript:test();">test.com</a><br>';
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is in your $set variable? Probably it has more than one element inside.

Comment: it contains only array.values getting from the database

Comment: Is it the jumbotron DIV it's outputting twice, or the col-md-3 DIV?

Comment: jumbotron div with result inside . this happens when i upload multiple images

Comment: You are printing a new `<div class="col-md-3">` for each row in your `$set`. Is that what you want?

Comment: got the solution guys , the issue with my set variable only as felippe said.        thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Seems like some code is missing, like the `$set` variable, but your loop logic *should* work.

```
$i = 1;
while ($i < 10) {
  $i++;
}

for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
  // echo $j;
  if ($j % 4 == 0) {
    echo $j ."\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 root:/opt/testing$
 -> php for.php

4
8
```